# Clicking BMW E36

Tags: engine, noise, bmw, solenoid, clicking

I have a 1995 BMW E36 with an M50B20TU engine.

When I turn on the ignition, but don’t try and start the car, I hear a regular clicking noise, which I believe is coming from the solenoid shown on this [video](https://www.reddit.com/r/MechanicAdvice/comments/fnjh39/bmw_e36_turn_on_ignition_dont_start_and_i_get/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=iossmf)

The car starts no problem, but the clicking continues, even when the car is running. Any ideas on what this is, how bit of a deal it is, and what I could do to fix it?

Thanks

M